# Реализация Multiline для TextBox в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Всем привет!

Работаю с WPF. Возникла следующая проблема:

Вывожу текст в TextBox (атрибуты: `TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" AcceptsReturn="True"` - для реализации `Multiline=true`). При изменении размера окна (меняется и размер TextBox) подвисает при большом количестве символов (20к+) в TextBox, и чем больше символов, тем хуже.

Как исправить данный момент?

Comment: Не использовать TextBox? Он вряд ли предназначен для таких огромных текстов.

Comment: @VladD, а какой элемент в таком случае использовать?

Comment: Попробуйте RichTextBox. Если не подходит по скорости обработки огромных текстов, придётся, боюсь, писать собственный велосипед.

Comment: @VladD, но тогда придётся построчно вносит данные в документ. И если честно, не представляю, что за велосипед придётся писать. Не подскажешь, в какую сторону копать в таком случае?

Comment: Почему с `RichTextBox` построчно? В какую сторону копать велосипед — ну, реализовать контрол эффективно и вручную, например, при помощи фонового разбиения на строки и вывод строк в набор `TextBlock`'ов, плюс ручная реализация курсора и редактирования. Хороший кусок работы, да.